# Unable to send messages to Google Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Everything is setup on my Android project from installing Android Studio, enabling Firebase, then assigning the context to my `onCreate()` method and then giving reference to my database URL.

Everything runs fine but when I try to send a sample message to my database from an `EditText`, nothing gets updated on it.

I am totally new to Firebase. Maybe I'm missing some basic things, but what? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was missing a basic thing.
I had to set authentication rules for my Firebase database to be used as public like this :
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

By default it is set to restrict any unauthenticated user from using it.

Everything works fine now. I can read and write data to my database.